# IWAB0503E Unable to update Java build path. Please check your system environment. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /lib/axis.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl, apache-axis, webservice-client

I got this error when trying to create a web service client in Eclipse. Already tried adding axis.jar into the build path but it won't fix. Does anyone know what happened or where /lib/axis.jar refers to? My Eclipse version is 2023-12 and the workspace uses Java 1.8. Appreciate your help.

```
IWAB0503E Unable to update Java build path. Please check your system environment.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /lib/axis.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.bundleentry.Handler.findBundleEntry(Handler.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.BundleResourceHandler.openConnection(BundleResourceHandler.java:182)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.BundleURLConverter.toFileURL(BundleURLConverter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.asLocalURL(Platform.java:641)
```

Comment: You are supposed to have the jar file and configure the right path to it.

Comment: @aled I have it, do you know how to configure it?

Comment: Where is the jar located? Share the current build path libraries configuration.

Comment: Already solved it by using older Eclipse version, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error , when i try to create a WebServiceClient project , couldn't find a solution until now ,but as i can see the problem happens only with the new Eclipse version, so using an old version of eclipse will do the job for now

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).